# Sending events from JS to Native (Java)

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native for an sdk. I need to be able to send an event from JavaScript to the native layer when a particular action has occurred.

The docs mention that it's possible to send events to JS, but I need to be able to send events in the other direction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you can just implement native method, which will act as event receiver?

Comment: did you find any solution ? if yes can you please share the code